# Multi domain caching with Memcache and Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, memcached

So, I've a problem, five domains on one engine, engine use Doctrine 1.2 ORM, all queries caching with memcache(Doctrine_Cache_Memcache). How make prefix to key for each domain and getting from cache by domainprefix_key? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a derivative that either extends or composes **Doctrine_Cache_Memcache**.  In the derivative you just modify the *id* by prepending the domain portion of the key before passing execution to **Doctrine_Cache_Memcache**.

Here's an example to consider using inheritance, overriding the **_doSave** method; the other public members can be overridden in similar fashion.

```
<?php
class DomainCache extends Doctrine_Cache_Memcache
{
    private function _getDomain()
    {
        // this could pull from config, a database, it
        // could even be hardcoded on a per-project basis - YMMV!
    }

    /**
     * Given the normal id the application would use, prefix
     * it with the appropriate domain.
     */
    private function _getDomainId($id)
    {
        return $this->_getDomain() . '_' . $id;
    }

    /**
     * Save a cache record directly. This method is implemented by the cache
     * drivers and used in Doctrine_Cache_Driver::save().
     * Overridden such that a domain-specific key is used.
     *
     * @param string $id        cache id
     * @param string $data      data to cache
     * @param int $lifeTime     if != false, set a specific lifetime for this
     *                          cache record (null => infinite lifeTime)
     * @return boolean true if no problem
     */
    protected function _doSave($id, $data, $lifeTime = false)
    {
        return parent::_doSave($this->_getDomainId($id), $data, $lifeTime);
    }
}
```

If you're interested in composing **Doctrine_Cache_Memcache** for example suppose you'd like to extend whatever provides the real work for **_getDomain**, you would implement **Doctrine_Class_Interface** instead.